# Convert dataframe to markdown table in Quarto

Tags: r, dataframe, markdown, quarto

I would like to convert a dataframe to a markdown table to use in html `Quarto`. We could use the [`simplermarkdown`](https://github.com/djvanderlaan/simplermarkdown) package with `md_table` to convert a dataframe to a markdown table. But the problem is that the output of the markdown is not converted to a html table. You can do this by copying the output and put it in the document, this is of course not automatically. Here is some reproducible code:

````
--- 
title: "example"
format: html
---

```{r}
library(simplermarkdown)
md_table(head(iris))
```

This is copied from output above:

|Sepal.Length|Sepal.Width|Petal.Length|Petal.Width|Species|
|------------|-----------|------------|-----------|-------|
|5.1         |3.5        |1.4         |0.2        |setosa |
|4.9         |3.0        |1.4         |0.2        |setosa |
|4.7         |3.2        |1.3         |0.2        |setosa |
|4.6         |3.1        |1.5         |0.2        |setosa |
|5.0         |3.6        |1.4         |0.2        |setosa |
|5.4         |3.9        |1.7         |0.4        |setosa |
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the output of the function does return the markdown format but doesn't automatically convert it to the desired output (like the copied code). So I was wondering if anyone knows how to automatically convert a dataframe to a markdown table in quarto?

Comment: How about using `output: asis` and `cat` the df?

Comment: Hi @shafee, I tried that, but that doesn't seem to work. The output is still the same.

Comment: Weird, it is working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `output: asis` and `cat`.

````
--- 
title: "example"
format: html
---

```{r}
#| output: asis
library(simplermarkdown)
cat(md_table(head(iris)))
```
````

---

[image: markdown table converted from dataframe using simplermarkdown pkg]

Answer (score 4):

Why going the extra way to `cat` the generated `md` table and output `asis` to generate `html`, if you are using `knitr` engine anyways? `knitr`has a function `kable`for tableling dataframes to markdown, html, and pdf. so we can directly convert the dataframe to an `html` table, without using intermediate `markdown`.

```
knitr::kable(head(iris),format = "html") # output format specification is optional
```

[image]